# Announcements module: limit the number displayed

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I'm at the 2011 Ann Arbor Give Camp working on a web site for charity and need some help.

We're looking for a way to have a summary of the announcements on the main page, and the complete list on the full size News Page.

Is there a way to limit the number of announcements just on the main page to something like 3 or 5, instead of setting a time span limit? Or is there another module that could give us this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Go to the settings for your Announcements module and make sure Allow Syndicate is on. (http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/Module-Announcements.aspx)

2) Click on the RSS icon for your Announcements module to get the URL for the feed.

3) Add the News Feeds module to the main page. (http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/Module-News-Feeds.aspx)

4) Click the 'Edit Newsfeeds' link for the News Feeds Module and add the RSS link from the Announcements module.

5) In the News Feeds module settings, set the 'Number To Display' property to how many you want to see on the main page.

Now the module on the main page is just listening to the full page of Announcements. Done.

You have to go to the Announcements module to add new items, but the two will stay in-sync.